# Multiple sound files not playing on android phone

Tags: android, mobile, html5-audio

I have an application where I included a few audio files in ogg format in the markup with HTML5 audio tags and I'm trying to play sounds based on a event. I'm simply grabbing the id of the sound file and playing it with sound.play() function. 
The strange thing about it is that the first sound is played all right but none after that.
I did a lot of research but couldn't find a real solution to this. Is it even possible to play sounds one after the other based on an event in an android browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the sound on a mobile phone can only be played when an event is fired. Also, the sound should be played directly in the event handler. Any delay (imagine setTimeout()) would not play the sound. I had to resort to a new handler to play all the sounds.
Most of the issues I faced were only on chrome browser for phones. Rest of the browsers seem to be responding well.

Answer (score 0):

Most mobile devices require (for HTML5 Audio) direct user interaction and that the call to `.play()` be called in the same callstack as that interaction. You should be able to call `.play()` on another audio when one audio triggers its `ended` event as well.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but it's actually not possible. It's sort of a card game for mobile phone where a card shows a word with a sound , then an image and then user input is required. Once user provides input, the correct or wrong card is shown and then again the card with a word is shown. That's where the sound is played second time.